# Planet Class with variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a text-based space exploration game in Python. I would like the planets to be assigned attributes based on their type (gas giant, terrestrial, ice giant). I have a class with mass, density, gravity, radius, resources, and number of moons. My question is what is the best way to define these variables? Here is what I have so far.

```
class GasGiant:
    def __init__(self, mass, density, gravity, radius, resources, moons=None):
        if moons is None:
            moons = random.radint(1,20)
        self.mass = mass
        self.density = density
        self.gravity = gravity
        self.radius = radius
        self.resources = resources
        self.moons = moons
```

Comment: Is there something in particular you don't like about your current solution?

Comment: What you have done is indeed the best way. And that is how variables are initialized in a class.

Comment: @Ryan A dictionary containing those values would make the variables less mutable, I believe, if that is what you are aiming for. But as Ram said, that is the perfectly normal and fine way to initialize variables in a class.

Comment: Yup! What you've done is fine. If you are not going to have any class methods, you might want to use python dataclasses instead.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of structure it looks fine, but if this is just a data object, then I would highly recommend using a dataclass.

Dataclasses allow for less boilerplate and provide many usefull methods like a constructor, equality, and string, repr, hashing, etc.

Also by using type annotations you provide better readability for what the fields are, and enable tools like mypy to do static analysis of code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
import random


@dataclass
class GasGiant:
    mass: float
    density: float
    gravity: float
    radius: float
    resources: list[str]
    moons: int = field(default_factory=lambda: random.randint(1, 20))
```

Answer (score 0):

- Maybe you want this feature to auto set self value?

#### code:

```
from functools import wraps
import inspect
import random
def initializer(func):
    names, varargs, keywords, defaults = inspect.getargspec(func)

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kargs):
        for name, arg in list(zip(names[1:], args)) + list(kargs.items()):
            setattr(self, name, arg)

        for name, default in zip(reversed(names), reversed(defaults)):
            if not hasattr(self, name):
                setattr(self, name, default)

        func(self, *args, **kargs)

    return wrapper

class GasGiant:
    @initializer
    def __init__(self, mass, density, gravity, radius, resources, moons=None):
        if self.moons is None:
            self.moons = random.randint(1,20)
    
g = GasGiant(1,2,3,4,5)
print(g.__dict__)
g = GasGiant(1,2,3,4,5,6)
print(g.__dict__)
```

#### result:

```
{'mass': 1, 'density': 2, 'gravity': 3, 'radius': 4, 'resources': 5, 'moons': 16}
{'mass': 1, 'density': 2, 'gravity': 3, 'radius': 4, 'resources': 5, 'moons': 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

If something is likely to vary based on different instances of class then it is recommended to set it in **init**.

Otherwise, if it's something you want it to remain same for all instances of the class, it should be set directly in the class definition.

If your class is inheriting from some other class, then you have to put the name of that class from which it is inheriting in the paranthesis

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("base class")

class firstChild(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        Base.__init__(self)
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm a beginner to python myself but maybe you can do something like this:

```
class GasGiant:
    def __init__(s, mass, density, gravity, radius, resources,moons=random.radint(1,20)):
        s.mass,s.density,s.gravity,s.radius,s.resources,s.moons = mass,density,gravity,radius,resources,moons
```

It is just pretty much cramping everything into smaller spaces.

Comment: This is way less readable than the answer.

Comment: This is same as what the OP has done. What changes do you see in your solution?

Comment: I am sorry the answer was disappointing. I thought he wanted the code to be smaller.